# Gensym procedure with larceny r7rs

Tags: scheme, r7rs

Under `larceny r7r6` for scheme, I am trying to use the `gensym` procedure as it is apparently defined [in the documentation](http://www.larcenists.org/Documentation/Documentation0.98/user-manual.html#id2544582).

When calling it (either in file or in console by typing `larceny -r7r6`), I get an error message saying that gensym is an undefined global variable.

Did I forget an import or is it not available ? Is there a new name or an implementation I can find anywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gensym` procedure is defined in neither R6RS or R7RS. So you need to import it separately if you want to use it in the R6RS/R7RS environment like this:

```
(import (primitives gensym))
```

It might be better to use the `generate-temporaries` procedure which is defined in `(rnrs)` returning a list of temporary identifiers. You can use it to generate a fresh symbol like this

```
(apply syntax->datum (generate-temporaries '(a)))
```

This would return a list which contains only one symbol as its element.